# Custom React hook: A way to persist a value after component unmounts?

Tags: reactjs, webpack, react-hooks

I am writing a custom hook that needs to store a piece of data and keep it even if the component is unmounted and then mounted again. The components it is used with are guaranteed to be singletons, and so I came up with a pretty ugly solution, roughly:

```js
const state = {}
const useCustomHook = () => {
    const { index, input } = /^.*renderWithHooks/gm.exec(new Error().stack);
    const id = input.substr(6, index - 6);
    if (!state[id]) state[id] = value;
}
```

The problem is that React gets minified by webpack in production, so the regex stops working. I can solve it by making it even uglier, importing `renderWithHooks` and forcing its name with `Object.defineProperty()`. Is there any better way to do this? Either a different approach altogether, or perhaps a way to configure Webpack to prevent uglifying a specific function name?